# For phonosemantic 和, what semantic notions underlie "mouth" and "harmony"?

Tags: etymology

How did [口](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A3) (mouth, opening) semantically shift to mean harmony for [和](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C#Chinese)? [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%92%8C) doesn't expound.

> Synopsis  : 「[和](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%92%8C)」字從「[口](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%A3)」，「[禾](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A6%BE)」聲，表示和諧。
>
> Elaboration: 金文從「[口](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%A3)」，「[禾](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A6%BE)」聲，表示和睦、和洽，中山王圓壺：「馭右和同」，《禮記．孔子閒居》：「無體之禮，上下和同。」《左傳．成公十六年》：「和同以聽」。《說文》：「和，相譍也。从口禾聲。」段玉裁改為「相應也」，注云：「古唱和字不讀去聲。」

I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%92%8C).

[image]

Comment: @dROOOze Thanks. I've asked this at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look up in the Outlier dictionary for Pleco says that for 和, the 口 component drifted as "to mediate; make peace" (resulting in harmony, which is very hard without a mouth) → "combine; mix" → "and" and "warm". They refer to:

> 季旭昇，2004《說文新證》，台北：藝文印書館印行，2014年9月第二版。